# Get C# enum descriptions with python.net?

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I'm using python.NET with a C# API. The dlls load ok, and I can find the enum I need, but can't figure out the right syntax for accessing it's values, names, and descriptions.

I'm not too familiar with C#, but think the enum is something like

```
public enum Things 
{
    X1,
    X2,
    X3,
    X4
}
```

and I'm trying to do the equivalent of e.g.

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Things));
```

although I also want to access the names and descriptions. There's a 'GetNames' method, and an 'Overloads' method which I think might be what's required for those.

I'm stuck on the syntax required to use unbound methods in python.Net.

```
In[1]: Things.GetNames
Out[1]: <unbound method 'GetNames'>
```

I can get individual values

```
In[2]: Things.X1
Out[2]: 21
```

but I would really like to understand the proper way to get this information--and the descriptions, which I can't currently find--using Python.NET.

---

ETA1: Figured out part of what I am doing wrong. Can get values and names as follows:

```
from System import Enum
values = Enum.GetValues(Things)
names = Enum.GetNames(Things)
```

The above return System.String[] but I can iterate over them in a list comprehesion to get lists of names and values.

but still unsure how to get the descriptions. Don't see any obvious methods for this.

```
In [17]:dir(Enum)
Out[17]: 
['CompareTo',
 'Equals',
 'Finalize',
 'Format',
 'GetHashCode',
 'GetName',
 'GetNames',
 'GetType',
 'GetTypeCode',
 'GetUnderlyingType',
 'GetValues',
 'HasFlag',
 'IsDefined',
 'MemberwiseClone',
 'Overloads',
 'Parse',
 'ReferenceEquals',
 'ToObject',
 'ToString',
 'TryParse',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__overloads__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

ETA2: The approach I was using was fine, but the API turned out to be buggy.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
from System import Enum

Enum.GetName(Things, 21) # returns "X1"
```

Comment: An answer starting with *"try"* is always a red flag. Is this a solution? Then don't write "try", describe what it does and how it solves OPs problem. Is this a question in disguise? (*"Can you try this and report back if it helps?"*) Then please don't post it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that this works with pythonnet 2.5.2.